# Axial loaded bars problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, statics, stress-strain

I completely disagree with the following calculations:
[image]

Based on my understanding, there is no force either internal or external applied to the Green bar, so it should be 0N. The reaction (internal) force in the Blue bar is 120N to the left. The reaction (internal) force in the Grey bar is 90N to the left. Do you agree or not? It is really confusing how to calculate these!

Comment: What is an "axial force diagram"? Is this something that engineers use? This is not common practice within the physics community, as far as I know. Can you explain what it is? Can you explain what $P(x)$ is? Can you describe the actual situation that this diagram is illustrating?

Comment: I Googled "axial force diagram" and watched a short video, but I am still confused.  I can't tell what the P(x) graph represents.  Are the three vectors in your diagram supposed to represent applied external forces at various points?

Comment: oh should I go to the engineering stack exchange then?

Comment: If engineers are more familiar with the jargon and notation you are using then they may be able to help more quickly.  But if you can add enough explanation so physicists can understand what is being represented, then they should be able to help as well, I think.

Comment: I think the picture is self-explanatory, what you do not understand? the axial force diagram is the diagram that represents the axial internal forces applied.